# angularjs controller could not read json file

Tags: angularjs, json

In the below code,

```
/* app.js*/
var app = angular.module('Sample', []);
```

---

```
/* Controller.js*/
app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('result.json').
            then(function(data) {$scope.tabular_data = data;} , function(data) {console.log("My error: " + data)} );


});
```

---

```
[{
    "name": "Brokerage Account 3",
    "marketValue": "1999990",
    "cash": "1995826",
    "legend": "orange"
}, {
    "name": "Account 3",
    "marketValue": "1949990",
    "cash": "1695856",
    "legend": "darkorange"
}]
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app_style.css">

    <!-- Libs -->
    <script src="angular.js"></script>

    <!-- Application -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="Controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Sample">
   .....
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content" ng-controller="Controller"></div>
</body>
```

---

controller code could not read the json file.

online tool verifies that json file is a valid file

Dev tool console does not show any error.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Could you add your html please?

Comment: @PankajParkar Please find the html

Comment: On a completely different note, the json data shouldn't be having `,` after "value":" XXX"

Comment: have you added `ng-controller="Controller"` on page to initialize controller.?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes , I added to `div` tag, as shown in query

Comment: Why are you using json when the user could have json turned off?

Comment: @ajaxGuru Do you want me to hard code  the data in controller?

Comment: @ajaxGuru How would a person turn off JSON? Surely you mean JS in which case your question makes no sense on a question about AngularJS...

Comment: json can be turned off if javascript is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is an issue with your json. Try without ending comma `,`.

```
[{
    "name": "Name1",
    "Value": "1000"
}, {
    "name": "Name2",
    "Value": "1949990"

}]
```

Whenever using JSON always validate them at http://jsonlint.com/

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m7kb9Vp2TvDQmjDACPo8?p=preview)

Comment: If above is problem..then he should have get error in console..but he is not getting the console error..

Comment: Yeah..that is wierd. I had a similar situation before. So I guess that it might be json linting error. And I saw your Plunkr. After I added those extra comma there wasn't any output.

Comment: online tool says json is valid

Answer (score 0):

Seems line you missed a closing bracket at the end. Try this:

```
app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('result.json')
        .then(
            function(data) {
                //$scope.tabular_data = data;
                console.log("Success!");
            },
            function(data) {
                console.log("My error: " + data)
            }
        );
});
```